# Writing to a file and reading it from a subprocess in python?

Tags: python, file, process, subprocess

I'm creating a text file, and immediately after calling a subprocess that does some computation based on the text file.

When I call the subprocess by itself, it's able to read from the file as expected, but when I try to create a file and write to it immediately before, it is not able to read from the file.

```
f = open('name_data.txt', 'w')
f.write(name)
f.close()

cmd = ['g2p-seq2seq', '--decode', 'name_data.txt', '--model', 'g2p-seq2seq-cmudict']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
#etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
open("Edited.py", "w").write("Thing To Write")
A = subprocess.Popen('Command you want to call', shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
print(A.communicate())
```

Comment: Is `subprocess.check_output` interchangeable with `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: I tried `print(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True))`, with `cmd` as declared in the question, but the error message is telling me cmd returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: I've edited it to suit your needs. It should not work without hinder. If you have any problems please let me know, as it works 100% for me.

Comment: Is `TYPE "C:\\Users\\danie\\Documents\\Robori rerun\\cache.txt"` just a path to the file, or is it something more?

Comment: If I'm understanding your code correctly,  it appears that you're simply opening the file, whereas I'm trying to call another program that takes the file as an argument